# go pprof doesn't work in different platform

Tags: go, pprof

My application is running on CentOS，and when I run `curl localhost:port/debug/pprof/profile > some.pprof`，and run `go tool pprof some.pprof`, it works. But When I use `scp` copying the `some.pprof` file to my mac and run `go tool pprof some.pprof`,it doesn't work any more,command `top` display only 1 line in which flat and sum both are 100% and the last row is the name of my application rather than the name of methods invoked.
Isn't the pprof file cross platform or something I've misused?

Comment: pprof depends on the binary used to generate the profile.

Comment: Yes. I taken pprof data and binaries from Linux servers and profiled them on macOS many times.

Comment: Thx a lot,it works

Answer (score 0):

as Adrian said, the binary is required for running pprof. So download the binary from server,put it into the same path on server, and it works